# Identify multiple Telegram bots using the same webhook

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I have three Telegram bots with the same hook address (or even with three hook addresses). I get input like this:

```
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($content, true);
```

How can I recognize which input is sent for which bot?

Answer (score 3):

You can set webhook URL with bot name as the query string.

For instance, use `https://t.me/hook.php?bot=Sean`, and you can use `$_GET['bot']` for each bot.